# Re-parenting a WKWebView after displaying it on one VC

Tags: ios, swift, caching, wkwebview

I'm using `WKWebView` as the central document object in an App, not just as a passive portal to the Web. The same document shows up in a few different places in the App, so ideally the view will render as efficiently as a native `UIKit` based `UIView`.

To avoid URL loading delays, what I tried was caching the view centrally, then when a navigation transition occurs and the new parent view builds itself, it grabs the existing `WKWebView` out of the cache and adds it as a subview, which of course removes it from the previous superview. Assume that it's OK to remove it from that previous superview because the latter is no longer visible.

I've noticed that this works *sometimes* but most of the time the web page is very unhappy in its new hierarchy -- it appears to apply a random scale and translation, leaving huge whitespace, or appearing many times too large, or half the correct size. Re-applying the same programmatic `NSLayoutConstraints` that work perfectly in the original superview, manual geometry manipulation of the `frame`, `setNeedsLayout()`, `setNeedsDisplay()` all have no effect when called from the new parent VC's lifecycle methods.

Clearly there is deep internal state with the WKWebView that I cannot figure out how to reset to make it happy in its new home. Is this just barking up the wrong tree? Should I be relying on HTTP-library level caching instead?

The goal is to avoid re-rendering the page which includes the HTTP transactions, document rendering algorithm, and all the inherent delays. After all it's been computed once. I wish to avoid redundant computation & network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

I'm was seeing this as well.
Moving a WKWebView from one parent to another (view of a navigation controller) causes the internal scrollview contentInset to update incorrectly (doesn't obey automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = false from navigation controller).

What I did was subclassed WKWebView and added just this bit to the class:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    self.scrollView.contentInset = .zero
    super.layoutSubviews()
}
```